# Initializing elements in an array in C would not be inserted in another Data structure

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating a code here in C where I declared and initialized an array of integers. I am to place all of these elements in a Partially Ordered Tree. But first, before I make a heapify function to satisfy the POT property, I tested first the insert function. But when all elements are displayed, only one element will be displayed and not all my elements in my declared array will be displayed.

Here is my data structure:

```
typedef struct{
    int arr[MAX];
    int last;        
 }Heap;
```

Here is my sample main function where I called initHeap() and insert():

```
int main()
{
    int elems[] = {10, 20, 5, 3, 9, 16, 2, 11, 10, 1};
    int x;
    Heap rec;

    initHeap(&rec);

    for(x=0; x<MAX; x++){
       insertToHeap(&rec,elems[x]);         
    }


    getch();
    return 0;    
    }
```

Here is my initHeap():
- initHeap() is used to initialize my Priority Queue to prepare for insertion.

```
void initHeap(Heap *A)
 {
     int x;

      for(x=0; x<MAX; x++){
          A->arr[x]=0;
       }
     A->last = 0;     
 }
```

my insertToHeap():

```
void insertToHeap(Heap *A, char x)
{
     if(A->last != MAX-1){
         A->arr[A->last] = x;
         A->last+1;
         /*Function call to heapify the POT*/          
     }
     else {
          printf("\nHeap is full!\n");     
     }
 }
```

here is my display():

```
void display(Heap A)
{
     int x;

     printf("Elements inside the heap are: \n");
     for(x=0; x<MAX; x++){
           printf("%d ", A.arr[x]);
     }

     printf("\nLast available cell: %d", A.last);
 }
```

I did not write yet the heapify function because I want to test my insert function first before I do the heapification. I inserted my elements in the last available space in my heap. My problem here is that whenever I insert an element from an array, the display would only show one element and not all elements I stored in my array.

Comment: Why is this tagged c++ if this is c?

Comment: I don't see any "display" here or even the `insert` implementation. Why are you posting an unrelated code, while omitting the obviously related?

Comment: void insertToHeap(Heap *A, char x)
{
     if(A->last != MAX-1){
         A->arr[A->last] = x;
         A->last+1;         
     }
     else {
          printf("\nHeap is full!\n");     
     }
}

Comment: Your question isn't clear tome.
Also don't dump code in comments, edit your original question please. (see the 'edit' button under the c++/c/arrays labels you have there)

Comment: `A->last+1;` -->> `A->last += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `A->last = 0` should be `A->last = x`.